# How to get frequency of dictionary values and map to fixed ordering of all potential values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a number of dictionaries that contain 10 keys. Values are sampled from a list of elements with replacement:

```
elements = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10']
```

in such a way that the frequency of each element can vary from 0 to 10.

```
d = {1: 'S2', 2: 'S1', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S5', 5: 'S3', 6: 'S5', 7: 'S3', 8: 'S1', 9: 'S10', 10: 'S7'}
```

How can I obtain a list that contains the frequency of value occurrences such as:

```
frequencies = [('S1', 3), ('S2', 1), ('S3', 2), ('S5', 2), ('S7', 1), ('S10', 1)]
```

Lastly, I want to map these to a list, where each index corresponds to 'S1', 'S2', 'S3', ..., such that the above frequencies would appear as:

```
[3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

That is, the frequency of 'S1' is 3, the frequency of 'S2' is 1, the frequency of 'S3' is 2, etc.

Comment: Why isn't your original dict a list? The keys seem pointless

Comment: Also what have you tried to do so, and how did it go wrong? Remember that this is not a code service so you should show some code you're actually asking about

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the keys seem pointless". The original dict is not a list simply because that was the way it was coded in the original program (the dict is the data structure used to store some data in that program). Yes, I know this is not a service, I have tried a function that generates a list and then appends values using reg exp. I have not been successful so far.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, show your attempt and how it went wrong and we will try to help you fix it or suggest other ways along the way...

Comment: just a question, how you are checking or knowing that S3 will be there as it is not in the original dict and in the output you are expecting that for S3 freq value should be 0 ? is there any reference you have stored for it

Comment: thanks for your question. We know 'S3' is there because the program is initialised with a list of signals that contains 10 elements, S1 to S10. And we want to obtain the frequencies for all these elements, regardless of the frequency. Yes, S3 freq should be 0 in the example.

Comment: i suggest you to provide that information in the question as this is leading to the conclusion that in result output seems  to have S3 based on a pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Get frequency of values

You could use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the frequency of the dictionary values.

```
from collections import Counter

d = {1: 'S2', 2: 'S1', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S5', 5: 'S3', 6: 'S5', 7: 'S3', 8: 'S1', 9: 'S10', 10: 'S7'}
counter = Counter(d.values())

print(counter)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'S1': 3, 'S5': 2, 'S3': 2, 'S2': 1, 'S10': 1, 'S7': 1})
```

### Map frequencies to a list (index corresponds to sample label)

Since the sample labels could be arbitrary strings, we need to map the sample labels to the desired indices. Then we can create an empty list and fill in the data for the randomly selected samples.

```
elements = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5', 'S6', 'S7', 'S8', 'S9', 'S10']
sample_index = {}

for i, label in enumerate(elements):
    sample_index[label] = i

final_output = [0] * len(sample_index)
for sample_name, frequency in counter.items():
    final_output[sample_index[sample_name]] = frequency

print(final_output)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

### Notes

- The dictionary methods are available on `Counter` objects, but `fromkeys` and `update` work differently. (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter))
- In Python 3.7+, [it has been declared](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) that dictionary keys will be preserved in insertion order. In previous versions, it is better to use `OrderedDict` if you need this behavior.

Comment: Since 3.7 it is not implementation-dependent, but guaranteed

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I knew the Counter function but it's been a while off from Python and I forgot this. Also, thank you for your useful pythonic tips.

Comment: Excellent answer @Christopher Peisert. Thank you. I understand what the code is doing, but could you briefly explain how the line ```final_output[sample_index[sample_name]] = frequency``` works?

Comment: @pyring The idea is to determine which position in the final list each frequency is to be placed. The dictionary `sample_index` maps the sample labels `S1`, `S2`, ... to their correct positions in the output list (0, 1, ... 9). The `final_output` list is initialized to all zeros. The `for` loop gets each sample name and its frequency, and the line `final_output[sample_index[sample_name]] = frequency` is basically assigning the fequency to the index position returned from looking up the sample label in the `sample_index` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the best solution but works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
mydict = {1: 'S2', 2: 'S1', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S5', 5: 'S3', 6: 'S5', 7: 'S3', 8: 'S1', 9: 'S10', 10: 'S7'}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mydict, orient='index',)

df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df['S'] = df.iloc[:, 1].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df.sort_values(by='S', inplace = True)

output = [0]*max(df.S)
x = 0
for s in range(max(df.S)):
    cout = np.sum(df.S==s+1)
    output[s] = cout
print(output)
```

#### Output

```
[3, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer @Xin Niu. I have tried with the following dictionary ```mydict = {1: 'S1', 2: 'S8', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S2', 5: 'S4', 6: 'S1', 7: 'S2', 8: 'S3', 9: 'S7', 10: 'S7'}``` and the output is ```[3,2,1,1,0,0,2,1]``` instead of ```[3,2,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0]```. Why are we missing some frequencies sometimes?

Comment: @pyring I think that's because you don't have 'S9' and 'S10' in your dictionary. In this case, I think you can safely assume the missing ones are 0. If you always have values in dictionary ranging from S1 to S10, you can modify: output = [0]*max(df.S) to output = [0]*10.

Answer (score 1):

So here is the solution that I ca up with for this problem.

**Idea behind**

- So first thing was to loop through the dictionary and the have them place in dictionary where now you have a compact number of occurrence of each
- Secondly now you loop through one with fixed occurrence per unit then append to results array
- So to have the sorted in terms of S1-Sn the you have to make your variable like I did and a counter that is always changing from S1-Sn

**Solution below**

```
    dictionary = {1: 'S1', 2: 'S8', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S2', 5: 'S4', 6: 'S1', 7: 'S2', 8: 'S3', 9: 'S7', 10: 'S7'}

seenMap = {}



for i in range(len(dictionary)+1):

    if (dictionary.get(i) not in seenMap):

    
        seenMap[dictionary.get(i)] = 1

    else:
        seenMap[dictionary.get(i)] += 1


numHelper = len(seenMap) + 1
counter = 1
results = []

while counter <= numHelper:


    index = "S"+str(counter)
    occurence = seenMap.get(index)
    if (occurence == None):
        results.append(0)

    else:
        results.append(occurence)
    counter += 1


print(results)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer @Ntshembo Hlongwane. I have tried with the following dictionary {1: 'S1', 2: 'S8', 3: 'S1', 4: 'S2', 5: 'S4', 6: 'S1', 7: 'S2', 8: 'S3', 9: 'S7', 10: 'S7'} and the output is [3,2,1,1,0,0] instead of [3,2,1,1,0,0,2,1,0,0]. Why are we missing some frequencies sometimes?

Comment: @pyring I just updated the solutions so what I did there is lets say your dictionary has s1-s10 when I get the results I cater for the frequencies within that range that is s1-s10 hence now when you run that code that I updated  with the input in your comment you get an output like this ```[3,2,1,1,0,0,2,1]``` hope that makes sense? But then on the last code I was omitting the last two frequencies that was a slight bug by me, so now even if you have s1-s20 the code will cater for frequencies in that range only nothing above that or below

Comment: Great answer @Ntshembo Hlongwane, thank  you very much